# Awk, Sed : How to parse and sum values from a string

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I've a string like this

```
Cpu(s):  1.9%us,  2.1%sy,  1.5%ni, 94.5%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
```

it represents the Cpu usage of my unix box.
Now I need to apply awk and sed (i think) to extract the current load of my CPUs. I'd like to extract the 'us', 'sy', 'ni' values from the string and then I want to sum them. 
The script should return 5.5 (1.9 + 2.1 + 1.5)... do you know how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The deal here is that you try to solve the problem yourself, and then post questions regarding specific issues.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I was about to answer but I agree with you.

Comment: for me it's a specific issue. I'm stuck on this. Maybe you're too smart for these easy questions? Good for you mr Butterworth

Comment: Why, guys? That's the right attitude for homework, sure, but this seems to be a real problem. Some of the real questions here are no doubt because people are genuinely stumped. I don't think an attitude of "go away and try again" is likely to help them out that much.

Comment: @mickthomposn But *which* bit are you stuck on? awk syntax, use of pipelines, bash variable substitution? And despite what some people might think, this is not a "plz send da codez" site.

Comment: As I said... you know how to do it, so for you this can appear as an easy question. This is one of my first scripts and I'm basically still learning. I had no idea if using awk or sed or something else could solve my problem (I didn't know of bc for example). Anyway, good for you that you have time to spend on useless comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, you just need one awk command. No need for other tools

```
$ str="Cpu(s):  1.9%us,  2.1%sy,  1.5%ni, 94.5%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st" 
$ echo $str | awk '{print $2+$3+$4+0}'
5.5
```

Comment: +0 converts the string to number(integer)

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline with `awk`, `sed` and `bc` will do the trick:

```
echo 'Cpu(s): 1.9%us, 2.1%sy, 1.5%ni, 94.5%id, 0.8%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.1%si, 0.0%st'
    | awk '{print $2"+"$3"+"$4}'
    | sed 's/%..,//g'
    | bc
```

gives:

```
5.5
```

as expected.

The `awk` will pull out the three fields and print them with `+` between them:

```
1.9%us,+2.1%sy,+1.5%ni,
```

The `sed` will strip out all `%..,` sequences where `..` is any two characters (`us`, `sy` and `ni` in this particular case):

```
1.9+2.1+1.5
```

The `bc` will evaluate that and give you the answer:

```
5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cpu='Cpu(s):  1.9%us,  2.1%sy,  1.5%ni, 94.5%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st'
echo $cpu|sed 's/^Cpu.*: //;s/%..,*//g'|cut -f1-3 -d" "|tr " " "+"|bc
```